# Можно ли значение в initial State (Redux) вставлять регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Уважаемые знатоки , подскажите пожалуйста , можно ли в  начальное состояние (redux) записывать условий оператор?
Я в app компоненте это делал . Мне просто интересно , можно ли делать именно так ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно, только где в примере регулярное выражение?

Comment: Дико извиняюсь ! 
Читал статью про регулярные и написал так .... условный оператор ))